# How do I set up a virtual environment with Flask using conda?

Tags: python, flask, virtualization, anaconda, conda

I wish to set up a virtual environment that I can use to develop web applications using the Flask framework for Python (3.4.2, Mac OS). I was given the instructions on how to do that [here](http://www.enigmeta.com/2012/08/16/starting-flask/), using the virtualenv. However, trying to follow these instructions I ran into a problem: I have Python installed via [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads#all), and upon trying:

```
sudo easy_install virtualenv
```

I am warned that I should be doing this with the already-installed `conda` package instead. I can't imagine that the conda way of doing things is much harder, but I also want to get bogged down with reading the documentation, because then I might not emerge back out of it again... So my question is, what's a quick way of setting up a virtual environment with Flask using Conda? And how can I then add more dependencies into this mix?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your mileage may vary, but the docs tends to be where the answers are.

```
conda create -n my_flask_env
source activate my_flask_env 
conda install condastuff
pip install otherstuff
```

Comment: [This doc](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/test-drive.html) in particular helped me out a lot.